# Development phase after successful ICO?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, ico, defi

I would like to know  about the development phase after successful ICO. Let's say I have an idea regarding a Defi Project but don’t have enough capital to implement it. So I launched an ICO using simple “ECR20 Tokens creation” contract and raise enough Capital to Hire a team.  My question is how New Team will Implement or start a defi project. Will there be new smart contracts by the new team that could freely interact with the initial  “ECR20 Tokens creation” contract or do I need to specify every single detail regarding the upcoming Defi Project in the very first  “ECR20 Tokens creation” contract ? OR  write code inside the “ECR20 Tokens creation” contract  so that other future defi contracts could interact with it initial contract. Thanks

Comment: If needed you can deploy a new token version.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely anybody is willing to invest unless you have what takes it to execute it before the ICO. Because it is unlikely you do not know what you are doing and you fail and people lose their money.

Even better you first build a working minimal viable product, then raise money.

[image]